# Why exchange basis exist in swaps

Tags: swaps, exchange, basis

For example, swaps traded in CME versus LCH are quoted with slight difference? how do we decide the theoretical boundary of the basis ? what factors need to be consider?

I think the principal to decide the basis should be some along the line of: if you were to go and do arbitrage between the two swaps(buy one and sell another), what would be the cost and risk associated with it ? Am I right one this ?

Comment: The difference exists due to initials margin imbalances between the two. [Clarusft.com](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.clarusft.com/cme-lch-basis-for-dummies/amp/) has several articles about this.

Comment: There’s also a paper by guys from BoE on this topic. I think the Clarus blog is quoting from that paper as well somewhere: https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/working-paper/2019/the-cost-of-clearing-fragmentation